# centered navigation fixed from scrolling when at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am having quite the headache over this and I've been trying to pull from several other posts on here with no luck. My issue is that I would like for my navigation to stop scrolling when it reaches the top of the page. Currently it will scroll off the page.

Little background, 
I am using wordpress and currently I have an external script file set up and it is enqueued into wordpress. the navigation is set up using php to work with wordpress.

you can view my live site at
[www.greenwellgraphics.com](http://www.greenwellgraphics.com)

here is my Header.php file:

```
    <?php
/**
 * The Header template for our theme
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php wp_head(); ?>


</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
        <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
            <a class="home-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>
                <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            </a>

            <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
                <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
                    <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h3>
                    <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></a>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
            </div><!-- #navbar -->
        </header><!-- #masthead -->

        <div id="main" class="site-main">
```

and this is my javascript I am using:

```
var num = 125; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

and the CSS:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #CCCCCC;
    border-top:1px dashed #CCCCCC;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Functions.php to show where / how i am implementing the script.

```
function get_Fixed_header() {

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script( 'add-GF-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js'); 

    wp_enqueue_script('add-GF-js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'get_Fixed_header' ); //hook to the enqueue function built into wordpress
```

*edited the java script to show that I am calling the div class out. sorry.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery somewhere else, as it seems to not be included in the PHP file?

Comment: I am using wordpress and it has Jquery built in, i am enqueueing it in the functions.php file, Ill update the main post with that code as well and a link to the live site.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you were looking everywhere, the problem is as simple as it can be.

Check your jquery selector `$('navbar')`, you are grabbing a html element instead a class'ed or ID'd element. So, fix it to it either `$('.navbar')` or `$('#navbar')`.

**EDIT:**

Instead of

> $(document).ready(function(){

use

> jQuery(document).ready(function($){

More info

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: I tried that with no luck, for what ever reason it still scrolls past the navigation element. thanks for the fast reply however.

Comment: Do you have a live URL of your website, so we can check it out? Look, there might be a lot of issues. You might have another error in your js code, or you do not use "no-conflict wordpress jqury wrapper" :-D, so on so forth…

Comment: yes, i added it above along with more code that shows how i am calling in the jquery. the site is [greenwellgraphics.com](http://www.greenwellgraphics.com)

Comment: That worked! now however i am having in issue where it jumps to the left side of the page rather than being centered... any ideas? I am not sure why it is losing the margin styles...

Comment: you did not set a horizontal position either with `right` or `left` in your css. The good practise is, set your `left:50%` and `margin-left:-%half px width of your menu bar%`, you can do it with right keyword as well